# How to use break inEnhanced for loop in jstl?

Tags: jstl

How to use break in Enhanced for loop in JSTL.
 Please check my code 
 **MyModelObject**

```
@RequestMapping(value="/g/{domainId}/{userId}/{userName}/fullProfile.htm" ,method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String showFullProfile(@PathVariable("domainId")Long domainId,@PathVariable("userName")String userName,@PathVariable("userId")Long userId,Model model) throws Exception {
     try {
                   List<Domains> domains = bal.getDomains();
                      model.put("domain",domains);
                }
                catch(Exception e)
              {
           }
return test;
}
```

test.jsp

```
              <c:forEach items="${domain}" var="domain">
                 ${domain.departmentName}

                </c:forEach>
```

My problem is every time i fetch only 6 records but  when my for loop reached 6th record i want to stop my for loop how can i do this

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution. Please try it, because I not tested.

```
<c:set var="count" value="0" scope="page" />
<c:forEach items="${domain}" var="domain">
  <c:if test="${count < 6}">
    ${domain.departmentName}
    <c:set var="count" value="${count + 1}" scope="page" />
  </c:if>
</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the varStatus attribute of forEach.

```
<c:forEach items="${domain}" var="domain" varStatus="status">
   <c:if test="${status.count le 6}">
      ${domain.departmentName}
   </c:if>
</c:forEach>
```